# How to clear the text within a UITextField using an IBAction?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ibaction

I thought this would be pretty simple but apparently it isn't, at least not to me. I have a `UITextField` declared in my `.h` file and declared its property, as well as an `IBAction` to clear the text within the field.

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField1;
-(IBAction)clearText:(id)sender
```

Then in my implementation file (`.m`) this is how I've written the method to clear the text.

```
-(IBAction)clearText:(id)sender {
   textField1.text = NULL;
}
```

But nothing happens when I press the button in the simulator. Why?

Comment: You may also wish to consider using the built-in "clear" button of `UITextField` instead of having a separate button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually connect the outlet?

Also I'd suggest using `nil` or `@""` instead of `NULL`

Comment: Yeah, the outlet is connected. I had tried @"" and nothing there and just tried nil, but still nothing happens. I also have a save button that uses NSUserDefaults and saves the text that's within the textfield. Would this be potentially throwing something off?

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
textField1.text = @"";
```

further check if the outled of textFiel1 is connected (black filled circle in XCode)
Add a log statement to

```
-(IBAction)clearText:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"clearText");
   textField1.text = @"";
}
```

to see if it is called.
If it is not called, check the outled for `clearText:(id)sender` , too.